# Mint 13 bug that prevents right clicking on desktop icons and numerous other symptoms

Tags: linux-mint, text, chrome, bugs

I use Mint 13 with Gnome Shell 3.4. For the last month or two I have had an issue that randomly occurs, and once it does only logging out or rebooting fixes it.

I randomly have a problem that causes at least these things:

1. Right clicking on icons does not work, if I do it acts as if I have right clicked on the desktop
2. In Google Chrome if I right click on a page to open a link in a new tab, if I go back to the original tab it is no longer functional until I reload the page.
3. When I am in a text editor (even in a Virtual Box system,) and click in the editor panel, it acts as if I was holding the `shift` key and highlights the text from where the cursor was to where I clicked.

My first thought was that this was a keyboard issue so I opened up Wire Shark and there is no input form my keyboard. I have searched around but have not been able to come up with a fix.

Let me know if you need any more info or if there is another [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) I should use since I'm new to asking questions here.

I have also asked this question in Linux Mint Forums [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=112010).

Thanks!

Comment: Standard advice for inexplicable problems (though this one looks more like a bug in some GUI library): run a memory test overnight (on Mint, I think you just need to pick “memory test” in the boot menu).